# Ruby on Rails associations not taking effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm brand new to Ruby on Rails and I'm having a heck of a time making sense of my associations.

At my company we rent out Scanner Packs that include scanners and servers.

When we receive a request for a scanner pack, ideally I'd create a new scanner package with the customer info and attach however many scanners and servers are needed.

Here is what I have for my three models, scanner_pack, server and scanner:

**scanner_pack.rb:**

```
class ScannerPack < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :producer, :reserved_from, :reserved_to, :scanner_id, :server_id, :scanner_pack_id

  has_many :scanners, :foreign_key => "scanner_id"
  has_many :servers, :foreign_key => "server_id"
end
```

**server.rb:**

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cat5, :power_cable, :router, :name, :status, :location, :id, :notes, :reserved_from, :reserved_to, :scanner_pack_id

  belongs_to :scanner_pack, :class_name => "Server", :foreign_key => "server_id"
end
```

**scanner.rb:**

```
class Scanner < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :location, :name, :notes, :serial, :status

  belongs_to :scanner_pack, :class_name => "Scanner", :foreign_key => "scanner_id"
end
```

I've googled and searched for quite a while now and I've noticed sometimes people say to remove the attr_accessible for scanner_id and server_id in the scanner_pack model because it will overwrite the association. When I do that, I get the error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:
```

In the rails console when I attempt to create a new ScannerPack I'm doing something like this:

```
scanner = Scanner.find(1)
ScannerPack.create(:producer => 12345, :scanner_id => scanner.id)
```

Then if I try something like:

```
scannerpack = ScannerPack.find(1)
scannerpack.scanner_id
```

it returns the correct value for `scanner_id`

When I try: `scannerpack.scanner.id` It gives me an undefined method error (I've also tried `scannerpack.scanners.id`). In my mind it should return the id of the scanner from the scanner object

I'm thinking that I'm either missing something very simple or that I'm completely misunderstanding how to do this. Maybe I should be using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` assocation? I'd appreciate any help anyone can give!

thanks!

Edit: Here is the whole project on [github](https://github.com/chantron/scanner_inventory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to have many-to-many association, here is how to achieve this, step by step.

We should create model that will contain `scanner_id` and `scanner_pack_id`. Let's name it `Pack` (I'm sure you will be able to name it better).

```
rails g model Pack scanner_id:integer scanner_pack_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

When you run it, you have to write appripriate "declarations" in your models:

```
class Pack
  belongs_to :scanner
  belongs_to :scanner_pack
end

class ScannerPack
  has_many :packs
  has_many :scanners, through: :packs
end

class Scanner
  has_many :packs
  has_many :scanner_packs, through: :packs
end
```

When you're done, you can easily bind `scanner_packs` with `scanner` (and vice versa) with (for example):

```
scanner.scanner_packs << scanner_pack
```

Comment: Thanks Marek. I left that code in last night after a fit of trying everything little thing I came across. I've removed it and It's still not working. I've also updated the original question with a link to the entire project if that helps.

Comment: I can assign the id of a scanner to the scanner_id in scanner pack but it seems that it's only assigning the integer and not making an association to the actual scanner object.

Comment: Here are some specific errors. I've assigned scanner_pack and scanner as I did in the original question. 

`scanner_pack.scanners
  Scanner Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "scanners".* FROM "scanners" WHERE "scanners"."scanner_pack_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: scanners.scanner_pack_id: SELECT "scanners".* FROM "scanners"  WHERE "scanners"."scanner_pack_id" = 1`

As you mentioned, that should return an array of scanner_ids?

`scanner_pack.scanner.name
NoMethodError: undefined method `scanner`

That should return the name of scanner 1.

Comment: Ok, let's go from the beginning. What do you want to achieve? Do you want `scanners` to have many related `scanner_packs` (and vice versa)? Or do you want `scanner_packs` to have many `scanners` and `scanner` belong to only one `scanner_pack`?

Comment: I'd like to have `scanners` to have many related `scanner_packs` and vice versa. That would require `:through` right? I decided to do it this way because I thought it'd be easier to wrap my head around and go from there :P.

Comment: Now it all makes sense! I was able to bind them all together! Now I'm off to break something else! Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other params from `belongs_to` and `has_many` methods, leaving only association names.

Error is exactly here

```
:class_name => "Server"
```

and here

```
:class_name => "Scanner"
```

Reference http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference (scroll down to `4.1.2 Options for belongs_to` and `4.1.2.2 :class_name`

Comment: Thanks Michal. I left that code in last night after a fit of trying everything little thing I came across. I've removed it and It's still not working. I've also updated the original question with a link to the entire project if that helps.